# My discord bot does not connect whenever I run 'node index.js'

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

It was working earlier (a few minutes before it stopped working) and now it just sits there with an open end attempting a connection. My console should print out "Ready" upon a successful start. However, it does not print anything out.

What I tried:

- Reverting to an older commit that I know was functional.
- Removing the proxy (I had to use a proxy because this bot is
  connecting to an API that is white list only and I did not want to
  send my personal IP).
- Restarting my computer. Restarting CMD. Restarting VSCode.

Nothing worked.

Here is the basic structure.

```
bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready')
})
```

```
bot.login(token)
```

This is my console:

[Command Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWnV6.png)

**EDIT:** It works now, but it wasn't working earlier. Everything else on my computer was working (Chrome, Discord voice chat, VPN) except for the bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may have run into an error. If you're not already handling errors, try listening for other events as [outlined here](https://anidiots.guide/understanding/events-and-handlers#errors):

```js
bot.on('error', (e) => console.error(e));
bot.on('warning', (e) => console.warn(e));
bot.on('debug', (e) => console.info(e));
```

Comment: smart. that completely slipped my mind. if this works out then well find out the next time it decides to die. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. If this ends up being helpful, please accept it as the right answer to help the community know it answered your question.